# The custom class variable is updating itself although not on the left side of the equation

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
class pac_state:
    def __init__(self, loc, action):
        self.loc = loc
        self.actions = [action]

next_state = pac_state(None, None)
new_state = pac_state(None, None)
new_state = next_state
new_state.loc = (3,4)
print "next_state after update ", next_state.loc
```

Somehow `next_state` is being updated when I assign something to `new_state`. They are supposed to be separate variables.

Why is the variable being updated although I did not use it in the equation?

Comment: Instantiate with the values of next_state instead of making nee_state a reference to next_state?

Comment: See [Ned Batchelder's Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: "They are suppose to be seperate variables" contradicts `new_state = next_state` in Python

Answer (score 0):

When you do `new_state = next_state`, both your `new_state` and `next_state` variables reference the same object. The previous value of new_state is lost since it is derefenced.

I guess you expected new state to be initialized with a copy of the `next_state`object, but that is not the case. FYI, the same kind of behavior happens in most OO languages, and with C style references or pointers.